# In Peep Show, why doesn't Jeremy just go on the dole?

Tags: plot-explanation, peep-show

In Peep Show, Jeremy has always struggled to hold a proper job or indeed a stable source of income. He's shown having to rely on Mark for basics such as food and has never paid rent (or at least I can't recall him once actually fulfilling one of his many promises to turn his life around). We also see him struggling with that and I believe there was a time when he briefly became homeless (haven't watched the series in ages).

So, why doesn't he just go on the dole?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Jeremy is supported by Mark and he even get money from family members so don't think that he is having any reason going on the dole.

Source Wiki:

> He is largely financially supported by his best friend and flatmate, Mark Corrigan, though various loans and free rent, Jez also appears to have been given money on many occasion by his mother (His nest egg), including topping up his mobile phone regularly as well as small bouts of employment in various arrears including working as a Music Studio Reception Runner courtesy of Super Hans (Series 1), a call centre courtesy of Toni (Series 2), as a legal secretary thanks to Mark's sister Sarah (Series 3) in a gym and as a personal handy man (Series 4) as well as working for one day at JLB and with Super Hans removals business "men with ven",He considers himself **very talented** and attractive.

Comment: Right, I would have thought this insufficient though and given his general lack of remorse and occasional sociopathic tendencies I'm surprised he has not resorted to the dole route.

Answer (score 3):

Jeremy claims to be signing on in

Series 4, Episode 4 - Handyman

> 00:09:56 'Oh, yeah, making smoothies at the Orgazoid's house!
>
> 00:10:00 'This is the kind of job I deserve. I've paid my dues, all
>   those years
>
> 00:10:03 'signing on, every bloody week.'

[Source](http://www.subzin.com/quotes/S523561757/Peep+Show/Handyman/%27Oh%2C+yeah%2C+making+smoothies+at+the+Orgazoid%27s+house%21)

Comment: Oh, well done, so he **is** actually on the dole, but that is indeed seldom referenced.